# Saving application instance on class

Tags: android, android-memory

Does keeping application instance as constant can cause memory leak? 
For example:

```
public class myLeakyClass{

    MyApplication app; 

    public myLeakyClass(MyApplication app) {
      this.app = app
}
```

I should also mentioned that I'm keeping an instance of this class at a different class that's acts as a singleton

Comment: You are holding a reference yo your `Application` class in a singleton? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication()

Comment: No, I have a java class which is a singleton that keeps an instance of MyLeakyClass. MyLeakyclass is what you see above (it is getting the application from the service that initiate the singleton)